# gensim installation error on macs10.15.7 with 3.9.0

Tags: python, gensim

I tried to install gensim by `pip install gensim` but it fails with following pile of error on **macs10.15.7 Catalina** in **python 3.9**

```
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:649:25: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
      return _FloatBigger ? numeric_limits<_IntT>::max() :  (numeric_limits<_IntT>::max() >> _Bits << _Bits);
                            ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    220 warnings and 20 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/jupyter/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/pg/1drqvjn54tbczc1pl5qd8qwh0000gp/T/pip-install-ndvn1a9y/gensim_2b2eae30f7e140c0af90d98d9e598905/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/pg/1drqvjn54tbczc1pl5qd8qwh0000gp/T/pip-install-ndvn1a9y/gensim_2b2eae30f7e140c0af90d98d9e598905/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/pg/1drqvjn54tbczc1pl5qd8qwh0000gp/T/pip-record-_xbpvhdn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/jupyter/include/site/python3.9/gensim
```

I googled and could not find any solution for this. Could someone share some pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to of of the [main gensim pages](https://pypi.org/project/gensim/) it might not be ready for Python 3.9 yet.

"Gensim is being continuously tested under Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8. Support for Python 2.7 was dropped in gensim 4.0.0 – install gensim 3.8.3 if you must use Python 2.7"

You can "downgrade" your Python version to 3.5/3.6/3.7 or 3.8 and it should work.